# Mahout in Tomcat giving Error

Tags: java, tomcat, mahout, datamodel

I have generated a Recommendation engine in Mahout. I have tested the Engine as a Stand Alone Java program.
Now I want to deploy it as a Web Application and hence I am using Apache Tomcat to deploy this Java Application. But when I execute my program on Tomcat Server, I get the following Error:

[image: ScreenShot of Error 1]

[image: Screenshot of Error 2]

I have added all dependencies and tried searching the net also on this but with no success. As I am new to Tomcat, requesting you to kindly help me out in resolving the stated issue.
Any kind of help is highly appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: It seems either you are missing slf4j jar (or) have wrong version of slf4j jar in classpath.

Comment: Thank You for your reply Nambari. I have added all slf4j jar files from the java project which is running as a stand alone program. The version of slf4j is 1.7.7. As I am currently new to this concept, requesting you to guide me in regards to what else should I check ?